# Sapply for counting changes

Tags: r

I want to get the maximum and minimum number of changes for filetypes.
DF:

```
filef                                     filetypedef    dev
 [1]/cvsroot/junit/junit/README.html      html           "egamma" 
 [2]/cvsroot/junit/junit/README.html      html           "egamma" 
 [3]/cvsroot/junit/junit/README.html      html           "egamma" 
 [4]/cvsroot/junit/junit/README.html      html           "egamma" 
 [5]/cvsroot/junit/junit/README.html      html           "egamma" 
 [6]/cvsroot/junit/junit/README.html      html           "egamma" 
 [7]/cvsroot/junit/junit/SUPPORT.html     html           "emeade"
 [8]/cvsroot/junit/junit/SUPPORT.html     html           "emeade"
 [9]/cvsroot/junit/junit/SUPPORT.html     html           "egamma"
[10]/cvsroot/junit/junit/SUPPORT.html     html           "egamma"
[11]/cvsroot/junit/junit/SUPPORT.html     html           "emeade"
[12]/cvsroot/junit/junit/build.xml        xml            "egamma"
[13]/cvsroot/junit/junit/build.xml        xml            "emeade"
[14]/cvsroot/junit/junit/build.xml        xml            "emeade"
[15]/cvsroot/junit/junit/build.xml        xml            "emeade"
[16]/cvsroot/junit/junit/build.xml        xml            "emeade"
[17]/cvsroot/junit/junit/build.xml        xml            "emeade"
[18]/cvsroot/junit/junit/new.xml          xml            "egamma"
[19]/cvsroot/junit/junit/new.xml          xml            "egamma"
[20]/cvsroot/junit/junit/new.xml          xml            "egamma"
```

Now he shows me the maximum and minimum of changes by every type but I want him to differate also betwenn the filenames.
Means datatype xml was changed max 6 times and min 3 times.

How can i make this happen?

This is my function

```
filetype.table <- function(x){ count(filename, filetypedef)
  mean <- sort(sapply(table(x$filetypedef),mean), decreasing = TRUE)
  num <- sort(sapply(table(x$filetypedef),length), decreasing = TRUE)
  min <- sort(sapply(table(x$filetypedef),min), decreasing = TRUE)
  max <- sort(sapply(table(x$filetypedef),max), decreasing = TRUE)
rbind(mean, num, min, max)
}

num is the number of different files
min and max is the minimum and maximum  number of changes for that file
mean is is the mean number of changes of the filetype
```

At the Moment he only works with the filetypes but i want it to work also with the filef row.
For example:
He shows me the maximum and minimum of changes by every type but I want him to differate also betwenn the filenames.
Means datatype xml was changed max 6 times and min 3 times.

The output should be like:

```
      html   xml
min   5      3
max   6      6
mean  5.5    4.5
num   2      2
```

Comment: Please show an example for your desired output since I don't understand what you are looking for.

Comment: So given your shown data, what output do you expect?

Comment: see updated question

Comment: just one more question: Is it possible to switch row and collum names?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The trick here is to pass multiple columns to `table`.

```
changes = table(df[, c("filef", "filetypedef")])
apply(changes, 2, range)
```

```
      filetypedef
       html xml
  [1,]    0   0
  [2,]    6   6
```

Here your minimum will often be zero. It looks like you are not interested in zeroes, so you could get rid of them by setting them to `NA`.

```
changes[changes==0] = NA
apply(changes, 2, range, na.rm = TRUE)
```

This gives the result as described in your question. It is also scaleable to any number of filetypes.

```
      filetypedef
       html xml
  [1,]    5   3
  [2,]    6   6
```

To add other metrics (as in the updated question), just rbind the results into one matrix:

```
rbind(
    mean = apply(changes, 2, mean, na.rm = TRUE),
    total = apply(changes, 2, sum, na.rm = TRUE),
    min = apply(changes, 2, min, na.rm = TRUE),
    max = apply(changes, 2, max, na.rm = TRUE)
)
```

```
      html xml
mean   5.5 4.5
total 11.0 9.0
min    5.0 3.0
max    6.0 6.0
```

Note: this code only uses base R functions (as stipulated in the revised question).

Comment: i want to use sapply at first and i want it in single operation like above. So That is possible for mean also.

Comment: Not sure I understand. If you want the mean, then just change the function in apply: `apply(changes, 2, mean, na.rm = TRUE)`

Comment: But when i have a bigger dataset it sets min to 0.

Comment: If you have run the line `changes[changes==0] = NA`, then this should not happen. Without seeing your bigger dataset and your code, it is a bit hard to guess what might be happening here.

Comment: Just one question, How cann i switch row an collumn names? So collumnnames are rowname vice versa

Comment: To transpose a matrix, use the function `t()`.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose, the `[1]` - `[20]` aren't really part of your filenames, so I remove them.

```r
df %>% 
  mutate(filename = gsub("\\[[0-9]{1,2}]", "", df$filef)) %>% 
  count(filename, filetypedef) %>% 
  group_by(filetypedef) %>% 
  summarise(min=min(n), max=max(n))
```

This gives

```
# A tibble: 2 x 3
  filetypedef   min   max
  <chr>       <int> <int>
1 html            5     6
2 xml             3     6
```

Comment: I want to use sapply for min and max each. I want to have single operations for min and max just the way i did it above.

Comment: You can easily transform my code into one line and without `%>%` if you want to. But why? And why do you want to use `sapply`?

Comment: i want to use the smallest ammount of libraries and in your code ist the count operation and it is noct part of the basic packages of r.

Comment: Okay, you didn't mention the usage of base R only in your question.